# Can't deploy react application

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages

I have tried many times and still cant deploy my react application. These were all the steps that I took:

1. Install NodeJS + GIT
2. Create a new repository on Github page (react-website-estate)
3. In the terminal (VS Code): `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`
4. In the package.json file, I added these lines

   {
   "homepage": "http://simonpham-webdev.github.io/react-website-estate",
   "name": "react-website-estate",
   ...}

   "scripts": {
   "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
   ...
   }
5. `git init`
6. `git remote add origin https://github.com/simonpham-webdev/react-website-estate.git`
7. `git status`
8. `git add .`
9. `git commit -m "deploy my react application"`
10. `npm run deploy`    --> then login in the github
11. `git push -u origin master`
12. Go into the github page settings and changed the branch to **master** And this is what I got: https://simonpham-webdev.github.io/react-website-estate/

[This is what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJVtQ.png)

[This the git path in the settings.json in case it has anything to do with the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skFko.png)

Images are attached in the blue links above
I would appreciate any help :( Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any error when you run `npm run deploy` ?? and you actually don't need to push your repo after deploying

Comment: No. There is no error. i followed a tutorial on youtube but the page couldn’t be deployed